# Atmosphere.js recognise client own traffic

Tags: javascript, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I'm using Atmosphere on the server with Atmosphere.js in the client to handle the connections.

Currently each client is sending, and receiving all data.

I need each client to ignore, or better still not receive the data it sends.

Is it better to try and do this in the client on something on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Set a UUID on the client and attach to object, and check if that object is yours. Bingo.